# Hooks @Before and @after are called twice in the beginning

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, cucumber, hook

I am very new to Automated testing and Cucumber too. I have written a simple cucumber-Junit example with three scenarios.

I am expecting `@Before` to be called in the beginning of each scenario and `@After` to be called after each scenario. So in total they should be executed only three times as there are three scenarios.

When I run my following step definition, first of all `@Before` is called, then `@After`, then again `@Before`, then Scenario 1, then `@After`, then `@Before`, then Scenario 2, then `@After`, then directly Scenario 3. Hence No `@Before` and `@After` is called before and after scenario 3 respectively. On the other hand they are called twice before the execution of first scenario. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? I don't have any .rb file in my project for Hook.

My `@Before contains`: `System.out.println("Setup performed");` and my `@After` contains `System.out.println("CleanUp Performed");`

```
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

public class CalculatorSteps {
    private Calculator calculator;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        calculator = new Calculator();
        System.out.println("Setup Performed...");
    }

    //Scenario : add two numbers - With regular expression
    @Given("^I have a calculator$")
    public void i_have_a_calculator() {
        assertNotNull(calculator);
    }

    @When("^I add (\\d+) and (\\d+)$")
    public void i_add(int arg1, int arg2) {
        calculator.add(arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Then("^the result should be (\\d+)$")
    public void the_result_should_be(int result) {
        assertEquals(result, calculator.getResult());
    }

    //Scenario : Subtract one number from another - With regular expression

    @Given("^I have a calculatorr$")
    public void i_have_a_calculator1() throws Throwable {
        assertNotNull(calculator);
    }

    @When("^I subtract (\\d+.\\d+) from (\\d+.\\d+)$")
    public void i_subtract_from(int arg1, int arg2) {
    calculator.subtract(arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Then("^the result should be (\\d+.\\d+)$")
    public void the_result_should_be1(double result1) {
        assertEquals(result1, calculator.getresult1(), 0.5);
    } 

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        System.out.println("CleanUp Performed...");
    }
}
```

Feature File looks like :

```
    Feature: Calculator
      I use Calculator instead of calculating myself

      #Scenario: Add two numbers
        #Given I have a calculator
        #When I add 2 and 3
        #Then the result should be 5

     @smokeTest
      Scenario Outline: Add two numbers
        Given I have a calculator
            When I add <num1> and <num2>
        Then the result should be <ans>

        Examples:
        | num1 | num2 | ans |
        | 2    | 3    | 5   |
        | 4    | 5    | 9   |

      @regressionTest
      Scenario: Subtract one number from another
        Given I have a calculator
        When I subtract 2.5 from 7.5
        Then the result should be 5.0
```

Output looks like:

```
    Feature: Calculator
      I use Calculator instead of calculating myself
    Setup Performed...
    CleanUp Performed...
    Setup Performed...

      Scenario Outline: Add two numbers # src/test/java/cucumber/junit/maven/cucumber_jvm/maven/calculatorFeature.feature:19
        Given I have a calculator       # CalculatorSteps.i_have_a_calculator()
        When I add 2 and 3              # CalculatorSteps.i_add(int,int)
        Then the result should be 5     # CalculatorSteps.the_result_should_be(int)
    CleanUp Performed...
    Setup Performed...

      Scenario Outline: Add two numbers # src/test/java/cucumber/junit/maven/cucumber_jvm/maven/calculatorFeature.feature:20
        Given I have a calculator       # CalculatorSteps.i_have_a_calculator()
        When I add 4 and 5              # CalculatorSteps.i_add(int,int)
        Then the result should be 9     # CalculatorSteps.the_result_should_be(int)
    CleanUp Performed...

      #@regressionTest
      Scenario: Subtract one number from another # src/test/java/cucumber/junit/maven/cucumber_jvm/maven/calculatorFeature.feature:23
        Given I have a calculator                # CalculatorSteps.i_have_a_calculator()
        When I subtract 2.5 from 7.5             # CalculatorSteps.i_subtract_from(int,int)
        Then the result should be 5.0            # CalculatorSteps.the_result_should_be1(double)

    3 Scenarios (3 passed)
    9 Steps (9 passed)
    0m0,074s
```

After having tried `counter` and @DaveyDaveDave code, the output looks like below: The printing of counter lines in the beginning are not at correct place, but atleast sems to be executed correctly. But I am still wondering why would it not execute `@Before`, `@Given` and `@After` in the case of the last Subtract scenario.

```
Feature: Calculator
  I use Calculator instead of calculating myself
@Before Count is: 0
@Given Count is: 1
@After Count is: 2
@Before Count is: 3

  @smokeTest
  Scenario Outline: Add two numbers # src/test/java/cucumber/junit/maven/cucumber_jvm/maven/calculatorFeature.feature:19
    Given I have a calculator       # CalculatorSteps.i_have_a_calculator()
    When I add 2 and 3              # CalculatorSteps.i_add(int,int)
    Then the result should be 5     # CalculatorSteps.the_result_should_be(int)
@Given Count is: 4
@After Count is: 5
@Before Count is: 6

  @smokeTest
  Scenario Outline: Add two numbers # src/test/java/cucumber/junit/maven/cucumber_jvm/maven/calculatorFeature.feature:20
    Given I have a calculator       # CalculatorSteps.i_have_a_calculator()
    When I add 4 and 5              # CalculatorSteps.i_add(int,int)
    Then the result should be 9     # CalculatorSteps.the_result_should_be(int)
@After Count is: 7

  @regressionTest
  Scenario: Subtract one number from another # src/test/java/cucumber/junit/maven/cucumber_jvm/maven/calculatorFeature.feature:23
    #Given I have a calculator
    When I subtract 2.5 from 7.5             # CalculatorSteps.i_subtract_from(int,int)
    Then the result should be 5.0            # CalculatorSteps.the_result_should_be1(double)

3 Scenarios (3 passed)
8 Steps (8 passed)
0m0,072s
```

Comment: Are you certain that the methods are actually executing in the wrong order, or could it just be that the logging is written in the wrong order? I would guess that the Cucumber output is coming through a proper logger, which might be doing some buffering, and only actually printing to the console at some point later than the logging happens, where your `@Before` and `@After` methods are writing directly to the standard output, which will happen immediately.

Comment: Don't think you need the second `@Given("^I have a calculatorr$")`. Try removing that from the steps file.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Good pointer actually ! Instead of having System.out.println directly in my hooks, I wrote method in main Calculator class. That avoids showing before and after twice in the beginning but before and after are not executed before and after third scenario (@regressionTest) respectively. However in my Runner class I have specified both the tags. format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}, tags = {"@smokeTest,@regressionTest"}

Comment: @Daniel You were right. I dont need second @Given("^I have a calculatorr$"). I removd them and Scenaros pass but the main problem in the question is still there.

Comment: I'd suggest, just to help you identify what's going on, adding a counter to the `CalculatorSteps` class - `private static int counter = 0;`, then in your `@Before`, `@After` and the `@Given` method, output the value of the counter and increment it - something like `System.out.println("In before/after/given - " + counter++);`. That way, based on how the numbers change, you'll be able to tell for sure whether the code is executing in the correct order, regardless of how it is output to the console. I think you'll see output something like: "In before 0"..."In given 1"..."In after 2"... etc.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I tried what you suggested. But it seems that the execution flow is not the way I expected it to be. i.e. The order of execution is:  Before -> Given -> After -> (again) Before -> Scenario (Given) -> After -> Before -> After (Here no given is executed for second scenarion and no Before, Given or After is executed for the last scenario. Also in starting it executes Before, Given and After without executing any scenario)

Comment: In your edited output, it looks like you have a `#` in front of the `Given...` line in the third scenario - do you have that `#` in your actual feature file? That is a comment, and means the `Given` statement won't be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the feature *is* executing in the order you expect, and that this is just an issue of how and when the output appears.

I've just copied and pasted your source, and added a `counter` variable, and when I run it I see the following output:

```
Setup Performed... 0
In given...1
...CleanUp Performed... 2
Setup Performed... 3
In given...4
...CleanUp Performed... 5
Setup Performed... 6
In given...7
...CleanUp Performed... 8
```

In other words, the numbers show that the ordering of these things is happening as you expect.

If it helps to convince you, I've created the following `RequiresSetupCalculator` which throws exceptions if it hasn't been set up before performing an operation, and also if we try to run the setup without having previously called `cleanUp`.

```
public class RequiresSetupCalculator {
  private static RequiresSetupCalculator instance;

  private int result = 0;
  private double result1 = 0;

  private boolean isSetup;

  private RequiresSetupCalculator() {
  }

  public static synchronized RequiresSetupCalculator setup() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new RequiresSetupCalculator();
    }

    if (instance.isSetup) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I have already been set up");
    }

    instance.isSetup = true;

    return instance;
  }

  public void cleanUp() {
    if (!isSetup) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I wasn't set up in the first place");
    }

    isSetup = false;
  }

  public void add(final int arg1,
                final int arg2) {
    if (!isSetup) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I haven't been set up, no calculating for you!");
    }

    result = arg1 + arg2;
  }

  public int getResult() {
    if (!isSetup) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I haven't been set up, no calculating for you!");
    }

    return result;
  }

  public void subtract(final int arg1,
                     final int arg2) {
    if (!isSetup) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I haven't been set up, no calculating for you!");
    }

    result1 = arg2 - arg1;
  }

  public double getresult1() {
    if (!isSetup) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I haven't been set up, no calculating for you!");
    }

    return result1;
  }
}
```

To test this, if you copy the above into a new class, alongside your existing `Calculator`, then modify your `CalculatorSteps` to use the `RequiresSetupCalculator` and to call the `setup` and `cleanUp` methods in the `@Before` and `@After` methods of your tests like this:

```
public class CalculatorSteps {
  private RequiresSetupCalculator calculator;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    calculator = RequiresSetupCalculator.setup();
    System.out.println("Setup Performed...");
  }

  ... (existing test steps unchanged)...

  @After
  public void cleanUp() {
    System.out.println("CleanUp Performed...");
    calculator.cleanUp();
  }
}
```

Now, when you run your test, if it still passes, I think we can be sure that the `@Before` method runs before every test, once and only once, and that the `@After` method runs after every test, also once and only once.

For me, this is working successfully. If you get exceptions being thrown when you run the tests, then there is something strange going on, but I'm fairly confident you will get the same results as me.